# HTML comment closing tag being ignored in IE

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

The following comment closing tag is being ignored in IE (all versions), so a ton of the following elements are commented out:

```
<a class="dynamic_embed_video">
   <?php echo '<!-- ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "embed_code") . ' -->'; ?>
</a>
```

In IE, the outputted comment continues past the closing tag and does not end until another comment open and close tag further down the page.

(FYI the reason I'm doing this is to dynamically embed videos upon the user clicking a preview image to quicken page load time)

Comment: Don't show us PHP. Show us HTML. The problem likely lies in the output of `get_post_meta`.

Comment: As @Quentin says, the HTML is necessary because that is what actually parses IE in a wrong way...

Comment: I'm guessing the "embed_code" is also outputting comments, which are getting nested.

Comment: What does `get_post_meta($post->ID, "embed_code")` return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you do like that

```
<a class="dynamic_embed_video">
   <!-- <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "embed_code"); ?> -->
</a>
```

Does it still ignored by IE ?

Also, check the code returned by your function and look if there is another HTML comment inside.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the output of `get_post_meta` inside [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to make it "safe" to dump in HTML output.